# Angular displaying REST Response after file upload

Tags: angular, typescript, response, console.log

I have an angular application and I want to upload a file and display a string based on the uploaded file.
I make a post call to a Rest API, this API returns a Response and I want to display the content of this response. Something is wrong however because I can `console.log` the content of the response but I fail to display it *normally* (i.e as a label or similar).
Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Here is `component.html`

```html
<div>
    <label class="image-upload-container btn btn-bwm">
        <span>Select Image</span>
        <input #imageInput type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="processFile(imageInput)">
    </label>

    <!--IT DOES NOT WORK  Displays [object Object] -->
    <input type=text name="prediction" [(ngModel)]="prediction" />

    <!--IT DOES NOT WORK  Displays [object Object] -->
    {{prediction}}
</div>
```

here is `component.ts`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageService } from '../../services/image.service';

class ImageSnippet {
  constructor(public src: string, public file: File) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) { }
  prediction!: String;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  processFile(imageInput: any) {
    const file: File = imageInput.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {

      let selectedFile = new ImageSnippet(event.target.result, file);
      this.imageService.uploadImage(selectedFile.file).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          
          this.prediction = response.toString();// IT DOES NOT WORK  Displays [object Object] 
          // console.log() WORKS: it logs something like this: {prediction: "jeges, tensor([0.0530, 0.0999, 0.8471])"}
//which is the exact string that I want to display
          console.log(response)
        }        
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

here is `service.ts`

```js
...
uploadImage(imageFile: File): Observable<Response> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imageFile', imageFile);
    return this.http_client.post<Response>(this.url, formData);
  }
...
```

and here is the API:

```py
@app.route('/api/image-upload', methods=['POST'])
def call_predict():
    imageFile = request.files['imageFile']
    prediction = makePrediction(imageFile)
    resp = make_response({"prediction": prediction}, 200)
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
```

Comment: you have a ```toString()``` call on ```response```, so its causing the ```[object Object]``` display, just have it like this ```this.prediction = response```

Comment: it does not compile.```Failed to compile.

src/app/components/image/image.component.ts:34:11 - error TS2740: Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'String': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 37 more.

34           this.prediction = response;```

Comment: hold on let me make an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a `toString()` call on your `response`, which is causing the `string` on display. So let us begin by fixing your file handler function right:

So start by fixing you service request handler like this

```
this.imageService.uploadImage(selectedFile.file).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.prediction = response;
  }        
});
```

So this change will cause problems in your HTML so we need to adjust that because `this.prediction` isn't a `string`

```
<div>
    <label class="image-upload-container btn btn-bwm">
        <span>Select Image</span>
        <input #imageInput type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="processFile(imageInput)">
    </label>

    <!-- here we'll bind according to the structure you gave in your code -->
    <input type=text name="prediction" [(ngModel)]="prediction.prediction"/>

    <!-- Since we have an object we cant just dump it here, so lets use a json pipe -->
    {{prediction | json}}
</div>
```

Lastly the member `prediction` in your class has to be type `Response`

```
prediction!: Response;
```

So this should work I think, try it out...

Comment: What works is :`prediction!: Response;`  plus `this.prediction = response;` plus   `{{prediction | json}}`

Comment: Oh okay, let me fix it...I thought it would be easier this that is why I changed it...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer, helped me a lot.